# Access webpageURL from NSUserActivity in React Native App Clip

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I'm throwing together but of a proof of concept using the new iOS 14 AppClips and ReactNative. I followed this tutorial here: https://medium.com/@nazrdogan/create-app-clips-for-ios-14-in-react-native-abfade233fea and am able to successfully run the app clip.

I'm struggling however to get the webpageURL for the userActivity in the react native code. Traditionally it would be something along the lines of https://medium.com/@nazrdogan/create-app-clips-for-ios-14-in-react-native-abfade233fea but only receive a null value. I have set the `_XCAppClipURL` in the schemes environment variables.

This is a hacky project so not too concerned about a clean implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of the tutorial. I have made some experiments with App Clips. you can follow this tutorial to get URL. http://mobiledevtutorials.com/handling-app-clip-url-in-react-native/

Comment: Is there a way to also listen for the App clip URL on the parent app? If the parent app is installed, Apple no longer launches the app clip. I'll love to listen to the URL on the main app too so I can also customize the experience